# EF Codefirst How to create separate table for derived class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have objects in their own tables using EF Codefirst. Now I try to produce an "archive" for changed objects living in separate tables for each of those objects.

For instance:

```
public class Person  
{  
    [Key]
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person_Archive : Person 
{
    [Key]
    [Columnn( Order = 1 )]
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Columnn( Order = 2 )]
    public DateTime ChangedAt { get; set; }

    public string ChangedBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I let EF create the Model it does **NOT** include the properties of Person in Person_Archive :-( Even if I add:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable( "Person" );
modelBuilder.Entity<Person_Archiv>().ToTable( "Person_Archiv" );
```

EF still does not repeat the properties from the derived class.

Has anyone an idea how to achieve that?

Thanks!
    Andreas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yeah, you need to call something like `MapInheritedProperties` method to do that.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("People");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person_Archieve>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("People_Archieve");
    });            
}
```

Comment: check this link out, http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Adding here for documentation sake...if you are using EntityTypeConfiguration to keep your data model from having EF specific references then you need to use Map property of EntityTypeConfiguration like below.

```
public class ArchivedPersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person_Archieve>
{
    Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties()).ToTable("People_Archieve");
}
```