# Entity Framowork Table per Type MapInheritedProperties Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a model in EF which contains very basic information about what pages will be contained within a website:

```
namespace Sapphire.Cms.Models
{
    using Sapphire.Cms.Data.Entity;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class SiteTree
    {
        public SiteTree()
        {
            IsHomepage = false;
        }

        public virtual int SiteTreeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        public string ControllerName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        [Index]
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1056:UriPropertiesShouldNotBeStrings",
            Justification = "This is a URL segment, not a complete URL.")]
        public string UrlSegment
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Index]
        public bool IsHomepage
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int ParentId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm inheriting the SiteTree class to create a SiteTreeHistory class which will be used to track changes made to the SiteTree:

```
namespace Sapphire.Cms.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    [Table("SiteTreeHistory")]
    public class SiteTreeHistory : SiteTree
    {
        public int SiteTreeHistoryId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Index]
        public override int SiteTreeId
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the table per type attribute `[Table("SiteTreeHistory")]` and when the table is created the properties from the inheriting table are not created.

I'm aware of the MapInheritedProperties method which can be called when the OnModelCreating is being invoked as mentioned in the following:

- [EF Codefirst How to create separate table for derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898453/ef-codefirst-how-to-create-separate-table-for-derived-class)
- http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

But I can't find an attribute that does the same, I was wondering if one exists and if not (as I'm not too familiar with creating attributes) whether it is possible to create one?

Comment: I did not understand why you do not want to use MapInheritedProperties  method?

Comment: From a management perspective, keeping information relating to the class with the class makes much more sense than having information relating to how it will be created and used scattered all over the place.

Comment: hey @Bonner, ever found an answer? Tired of creating EF configurations just for this one method.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa not yet unfortunately.